# How to calculate the closing price percentage change for a stock?

Tags: stocks, calculation, price

When viewing a stock on Yahoo Finance:

http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=ASC.L#symbol=asc.l;range=1d;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;

...I see that the last days closing price is listed under the stock name (currently Asos's last closing price was 5,025.92). Next to it there's either green text showing the stock has gone up or red text showing the stock has gone down. At the moment the price has gone up so it looks like this (in green):

25.92(0.52%)

I want to know how the figure of 25.92 is worked out. Is it todays closing price minus yesterdays closing price? I've tried calculating this but my figure comes out nowhere near 25.92.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous day's close on Thursday 10th October was 5,000.00

The close on Friday 11th October is 5,025.92

So the gain on Friday was 25.92 (5025.92 - 5000) or 0.52% (25.92/5000 x 100%). No mystery!

Comment: This is equivalent to the "percent error" formula from your high school chemistry/physics classes. Delta over original (or theoretical) value times 100%.